# Hide woocommerce product description and specification on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

How to hide woocommerce product description and specification on load.

Currently when product is loaded its description and 
specification load automatically. I need to hide this on load.
But when user clicks on description and specification tab, I need to show
the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn’t able to find it myself but adding this to your Quick CSS or custom.css works:

```
  .single .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.description_tab {
     display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend . I will check this

Comment: You know how to style product block in archive page , because i need to give border for each product in product archive page .

Comment: could you please help to solve this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526268/sql-query-to-download-order-report-in-woocommerce